# Regex: match patterns starting from the end of string

Tags: regex

I wish to match a filename with column and line info, eg.

```
\path1\path2\a_file.ts:17:9

//what i want to achieve:
match[1]: a_file.ts
match[2]: 17
match[3]: 9
```

This string can have garbage before and after the pattern, like

```
(at somewhere: \path1\path2\a_file.ts:17:9 something)
```

What I have now is this regex, which manages to match column and line, but I got stuck on filename capturing part.. I guess negative lookahead is the way to go, but it seems to match all previous groups and garbage text in the end of string.

```
(?!.*[\/\\]):(\d+):(\d+)\D*$
```

Here's a link to current implementation [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rFsd7g/1)

Comment: Do you have to use a regexp? Doesn't the programming language have a function to split a string at delimiters?

Comment: @Barmar sure it does, but I kinda wish to achieve this by matching patterns, as there might be cases that splitting can not handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the lookahead with a negated character class:

```js
([^\/\\]+):(\d+):(\d+)\D*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cnTRHz/1). *Details*:

- `([^\/\\]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `/` and `\`
- `:` - a colon
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `:` - a colon
- `(\d+)` - Group 3: one or more digits
- `\D*$`  - zero or more non-digit chars till end of string.